# How can I prevent the endIcon from getting focus when the Next key is pressed in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, kotlin, focus, android-textinputlayout

I don't want the end Icon of EditText to get focus when the next key is pressed. I have given the imeOptions as 'actionNext' . Now when I click the Next key , if the edittext is empty ,  it moves to the next edittext placing the cursor there. But if the edittext is not empty, clicking the next key shifts the focus to the endIcon. Is there a way I can prevent this ?

Comment: Did you happen to test this with the physical keyboard on your development machine? It turns out that doing that alters the touch/focus mode somehow, which ends up screwing with the search for the next focusable `View`. In my tests, using only the virtual keyboard doesn't cause any such issues, though there might be cases I hadn't considered. If it's still a problem, or a concern otherwise, the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59441475) seems to work for the most part. I could've sworn it flaked some tests last night, but I can't seem to reproduce that behavior today.

Comment: @MikeM. The problem here I am using the TextInputLayout inside a custom layout . So I am unable to specify the id of the next 'Edittext' particularly there. I am just including the CustomLayout using <include> tag.

Comment: Well, if you're using the physical keyboard, that's actually how it's supposed to behave, 'cause it's kind of assuming that the user needs to be able to reach anything clickable/focusable with just the keyboard, and the focus search changes in that non-touch mode to make it a bit easier. If you really do want to change that behavior, you might be able to do something with an `OnEditorActionListener`; e.g, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DS5t_akl8OXzGag9lgxZC_QVi_WO1o6c/view?usp=sharing. That will direct the focus downward, so it'll work as is if your `TextInputLayout`s are stacked vertically.